# How to create URL to open specific email in iNotes?

Tags: lotus-domino

How to create URL to open specific email in iNotes? To open specific view for mail, calendar or todo I can use URL as this one "....nsf/iNotes/Mail/?OpenDocument&PresetFields=s_ViewLabel;Sent,s_ViewName;($Sent) " .

But whats the URL pattern for opening specific email message when I know its UNID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL

```
....nsf/iNotes/UNID?OpenDocument
```

opens the document with the UNID in browser.

Example:

```
....nsf/iNotes/EDD83315F0BC6F2CC1257B81004B098C?OpenDocument
```

This URL does work for all kinds of documents (mails, calendar entries, ...).

If you want to have the possibility to navigate from the document with UNID to other documents in $Inbox with arrows [image] then you can use this URL:

```
....nsf/($Inbox)/UNID/?OpenDocument&PresetFields=s_ParentContentId;($Inbox)1,s_ViewName;(%24Inbox),s_InheritAttachment;false,s_SortOrder;1,s_SortColumnPN;$70&ui=portal
```

Replace `UNID` with the UNID of document.